# SQL Exception: Error converting data type nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, casting, sql-server-2012-express

Looks like a casting issue, however when casting is applied (to what i believe is the correct format) i still get the SQLException raised in Visual Studio Web Developer 2010 Express (VB.NET)

Start with a Stored Procedure that has 1 input parameter and 4 output parameters and relevant code snippets show below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectCompanies] 

@tickersList NVARCHAR(max) = NULL,
@YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies int OUTPUT,
@topEndToStartYear nvarchar(9) OUTPUT,
@middleEndToStartYear nvarchar(9) OUTPUT,
@bottomEndToStartYear nvarchar(9) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

SET @YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies = (SELECT TOP 1 ey.[Year] FROM company c, earningspershare e, earningspershareYear ey WHERE c.ticker_id = e.ticker_id AND e.EarningsPerShareID = ey.EarningsPerShareID AND c.tickerSymbol IN (  SELECT * FROM dbo.fnCSVStringToTable(@tickersList,',')  ) AND ey.Value is not null ORDER by ey.[Year] DESC);

DECLARE @topStartYear int, @topEndYear int;
DECLARE @middleStartYear int, @middleEndYear int;
DECLARE @bottomStartYear int, @bottomEndYear int;


SET @topStartYear = @YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies;

SET @topEndYear = @topStartYear - 2;


SET @topEndToStartYear = CAST(@topEndYear As nvarchar(4)) + N'-'  ; --ERROR

....
```

The relevant VB.NET code is shown below:

```
    Dim year As New SqlParameter
    Dim topEndToStartYear As New SqlParameter
    Dim middleEndToStartYear As New SqlParameter
    Dim bottomEndToStartYear As New SqlParameter


    'Add tables
    dadCompanies = New SqlDataAdapter("SelectCompanies", conn)
    dadCompanies.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    If Not IsNothing(tBx_c_tickerSymbol.Text.ToString) Then
        dadCompanies.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tickersList", tBx_c_tickerSymbol.Text.ToString)

        'year Output Parameter
        year = dadCompanies.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies", SqlDbType.Int)
        year.Size = 4
        year.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        'topEndToStartYear Output Parameter
        topEndToStartYear = dadCompanies.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topEndToStartYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        topEndToStartYear.Size = 10
        topEndToStartYear.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        'middleEndToStartYear Output Parameter
        middleEndToStartYear = dadCompanies.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleEndToStartYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        middleEndToStartYear.Size = 12
        middleEndToStartYear.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        'bottomEndToStartYear Output Parameter
        bottomEndToStartYear = dadCompanies.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bottomEndToStartYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        bottomEndToStartYear.Size = 12
        bottomEndToStartYear.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

    End If

    dadCompanies.Fill(dstCompanies, "company")
....
```

Points to Note:

- The stored procedure when executed from within SQL Server Managment Studio 2012 executes fine, without any errors.
- When debugging via Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2010 using IISExpress .NET v2.0.50727 the SQLServer Exception is thrown.
- Switching this line in SQL Server CAST(@topEndYear As nvarchar(4)) + N'-' (where the error is occuring) to N'-' + CAST(@topEndYear As nvarchar(4))  CORRECTS the problem, i.e. leading with a nvarchar character and then casting
- In VB.NET changing the value SqlDbType.NVarChar to SqlDbType.NVarChar.ToString CORRECTS the problem if i leave the problem line as CAST(@topEndYear As nvarchar(4)) + N'-'

I would really like to understand why this is happening. Even though i have some solutions they dont give me an explanation of why. I thought i had a good grasp on Casting, maybe there is something i am missing?

Comment: Will people never learn not to store numeric data in character columns...

Comment: The keyword is **[Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)**

Comment: You should [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) of the functions you are using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `AddWithValue` the second parameter is the value but you pass the `SqlDbType`. Instead use `Add`. This is one of the reasons which speak against `AddWithValue`:

```
'year Output Parameter
Dim Year = dadCompanies.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@YearInWhichEarningsExistForAllComparisonCompanies", SqlDbType.Int)
Year.Size = 4
Year.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

'topEndToStartYear Output Parameter
Dim topEndToStartYear = dadCompanies.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@topEndToStartYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
topEndToStartYear.Size = 10
topEndToStartYear.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

'middleEndToStartYear Output Parameter
Dim middleEndToStartYear = dadCompanies.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@middleEndToStartYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
middleEndToStartYear.Size = 12
middleEndToStartYear.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

'bottomEndToStartYear Output Parameter
Dim bottomEndToStartYear = dadCompanies.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@bottomEndToStartYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
bottomEndToStartYear.Size = 12
bottomEndToStartYear.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```